# Weird array_search behaviour

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php 

    $ray = array(1, "aa" , 0);
    echo "Index = " . array_search("I want to find this text", $ray);

?>
```

How to explain that the `array_search()` function returns existing index 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `array_search` uses `==` to compare things.  This makes PHP *convert* the operands so that their types match.

```
1 == "I want to find this text"
"aa" == "I want to find this text"
0 == "I want to find this text"
```

In the 1st and 3rd ones, PHP needs to convert `"I want to find this text"` to a number so it can compare.  When converting a string to a number, PHP reads from the beginning of the string and stops at the first non-numeric character.  So `"I want to find this text"` is converted to `0`.

So the comparisons made are

```
1 == "I want to find this text" => 1 == 0 => false
"aa" == "I want to find this text" => false
0 == "I want to find this text" => 0 == 0 => true
```

And, that's why you get 2.

To fix this, do this: `array_search("I want to find this text", $ray, true)`

The 3rd parameter tells `array_search` to use `===` instead.  This does *not* convert types, instead it compares them too.  That will give you `FALSE` since nothing matches `"I want to find this text"` in *both* type and value.